# The fast efficient way to normalize each channel of an image with different value

Tags: c++, opencv, c++17

I have to divide all the pixels of each channel by a value (normalization). What I do is split the image into three channels, divide all pixels and then merge back the three channels. Here is how I do it:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void insert_all(std::vector<T> &vec, Ts ... ts)
{
    (vec.push_back(ts), ...);
} 

std::vector<cv::Mat> rgb, rgbN; 
cv::split(src, rgb); //src is my RGB image

rgbN.reserve(3);
insert_all(rgbN, cv::Mat_<float>(rgb[0])/A0, 
                 cv::Mat_<float>(rgb[1])/A1, 
                 cv::Mat_<float>(rgb[2])/A2);
cv::Mat srcN;
cv::merge(rgbN, srcN_gray);
```

I think it is too much code for a simple normalization, is there a better way to do it, probably without spiting and merging?

Comment: seems to be overly complicated.... you can try to create a copy (with clone for example) and then transform from the std or the foreach of opencv... get the pixels as vec3f and divide each channel with the value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment you can try to do everything without separating it... with the least code as possible I think this is the way to go:

```
// dummy values, replace as needed
float A0 = 1.0, A1 = 2.0, A2 = 3.0;
// creates a copy to work in
cv::Mat srcN = src.clone();
// normalizes in one pass
std::transform(srcN.begin<cv::Vec3f>(), srcN.end<cv::Vec3f>(), srcN.begin<cv::Vec3f>(), [A0, A1, A2](const cv::Vec3f pixel){
  return cv::Vec3f(pixel[0]/A0, pixel[1]/A1, pixel[2]/A2);
});
```

In a similar way you can try other approaches, e.g. [OpenCV foreach](https://www.learnopencv.com/parallel-pixel-access-in-opencv-using-foreach/)  or the concurrency library.

## EDIT:

Here is my try with the OpenCV foreach... I have not tested it, but should work

```
cv::Mat srcN = src.clone();
srcN.forEach<cv::Vec3f>
(
  [A0, A1, A2](cv::Vec3f &pixel, const int * position) -> void
  {
    pixel[0]/=A0;
    pixel[1]/=A1;
    pixel[2]/=A2;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is short but little bit slower than my first solution

Comment: @Ja_cpp OpenCV functions are usually well optimized so I am not surprised that this is the case... however you can try with my edit to see if it gets better

Comment: thanks works slightly faster than both solutions